# Firebase database retrieve inefficient

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem. I want to show to a user spesific parts of the database according to his settings. For example, in my Firebase database, I have 'users' child and 'fruits' child. Now, I want to display to a user his favoarite fruits. The way I did it was saving in the user child the id's of his favorite fruits, get a list of those id's with addChildEventListener, and then use another addChildEventListener on the fruits section, so that in onChildAdded, I'm cheking if the current child fruit id is matching one of the id's in the list I made earlier, with a for loop. Keep in mind that there could be millions of fruits/favorites, this way seems realy inefficient and there must be other way I didn't think/learn about.

Comment: Can you please share as your database structure and what have you tried so far? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: look it was just an example, i already deleted it. I dont need help with the code because it worked, its just that the way i did it seems inerfficient,basically I need to get the concept of fetching defined list of objects out of the database according to the id's of the objects. if you can explain this concept to me it will be much appreciated.